# Why isnt my time format not working in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to format the date as follow:
 November 2, 2012 10:26:28 PM

I get the following error and I do not know why.

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Thanks for any help.

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss "); 
document.write("<p><strong>Todays Date is: </strong> " + now + "</p>");
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using four d's there

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript Dates don't have a format function.

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/datetime-functions#formatting. This talks about that.

Comment: Ok so Im new to javaScript what is the best approach to sold this problem. I have to do it  in that format cause is an assignment.

Comment: On that page: "Native Date formatting methods do not allow to specify custom format. So, function formatting functions are created instead."

Comment: Unless you want to use an external library, you have to do the formatting yourself. Here's a good link to get you started: [10 ways to format time and date using JS](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)